# KIK not recognising IOS 8.1.1.1

Tags: ios, firebase, polymer, kik

Created an app using Polymer and Firebase for KIK users however ALL devices Except IOS 8.1.1 devices work.

I used:

```
var os = kik.utils.platform.os;
typeof os.name    === 'string';
typeof os.version === 'number';
console.log(os.name, os.version);
```

As each device loads the app I can see what OS and version BUT IOS 8.1.1 remains a ghost and doesn't even generate an output. This means anyone on that OS cannot use the app.

Any one have ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Try checking `kik.utils.os.versionString`. That will have the non-numeric versioning.